# Need help INSERT record(s) MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, loops

I have an online form which collects member(s) information and stores it into a very long MySQL database. We allow up to 16 members to enroll at a single time and originally structured the DB to allow such.

### For example:

If 1 Member enrolls, his personal information (first name, last name, address, phone, email) are stored on a single row.

If 15 Members enroll (all at once), their personal information are stored in the same single row.

The row has information housing columns for all 'possible' inputs. I am trying to consolidate this code and having every nth member that enrolls put onto a new record within the database.

I have seen sugestions before for inserting multiple records as such:

> INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
>   (('$f1name', '$f1address', '$f1phone'), ('$f2name', '$f2address', '$f2phone')...

### The issue with this is two fold:

1. I do not know how many records are
   being enrolled from person to person
   so the only way to make the
   statement above is to use a loop
2. The information collected from the
   forms is NOT a single array so I
   can't loop through one array and
   have it parse out. My information is
   collected as individual input fields
   like such: Member1FirstName,
   Member1LastName, Member1Phone,
   Member2Firstname, Member2LastName,
   Member2Phone... and so on

Is it possible to store information in separate rows WITHOUT using a loop (and therefore having to go back and completely restructure my form field names and such (which can't happen due to the way the validation rules are built.)

Comment: Is your naming convention firm when it comes the num at the end of the var name?

Comment: @Babiker - I assume you mean where I have 'Name2', etc above? The actual values are stored in session throughout the process and run through mysql_real_escape_string(). In reality, the INSERT VALUE will look like '$f1fname', '$f1lname', '$f1phone', '$f2fname', $f2lname', '$f2phone')

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve. Are you saying that, instead of putting all 15 on one row like before, you now want to put each member on his own row?

Comment: @Ed Daniel - Yes that is exactly what i am trying to do. HOWEVER, I don't have the members in an array already (and won't due to the way I validate each field)

Comment: Hey JM4 i think making your application bend backwards because of validation might bite you latter on.

Comment: @Babiker - not sure i agree. The validation we run through is very complex and already uses another array titled [fields] which collects all POST data and runs through validations. Breaking that out and putting back into another array doesn't seem to make sense. Any suggestions how to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you form's structured so that all the fields are numbered properly, so that a "firstname #1" is matched up with all the other "#1" numbered fields, then a loop is the simplest solution.

```
start_transaction();
$errors = false;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 16; $i++) {
   if (... all $i fields are properly filled in ...) {
      $field = $_POST["field$i"];
      $otherfield = $_POST["otherfield$i"];
      etc...

      ... insert into database ...
   } else {
      ... handle error condition here
      $errors = true;
   }
}
if (!$errors) {
   commit_transaction();
} else {
   rollback();
}
```

If they're numbered randomly, so that firstname1 is matched with lastname42 and address3.1415927, then you'd have to build a lookup table to map all the random namings together, and loop over that

followup per comment:

well, if you absolutely insist on maintaining this database structure, where each row contains 16 sets of repeated firstname/lastname/etc.. records, then you'd do something like this:

```
$first = true;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 16; $i++) {
    if (fields at position $i are valid) {
       $firstname = mysql_escape_real_string($_POST["F{$i}name"]);
       $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["F{$i}lastname"]);
       if ($first) {
          $dbh->query("INSERT INTO table (f{$i}name, f{$i}lastname) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname);"
          $recordID = $dbh->query("SELECT last_insert_id();");
          $first = false;
       } else {
          $dbh->query("UPDATE table SET f{$i}name=$firstname, f{$i}lastname=$lastname WHERE idfield=$recordID");
       }
    }
}
```

It's ugly, but basically:

1. loop through the form field sets until you find a valid set (all required fields filled in, valid data entered, etc..
2. Insert that data set into the database to create the new record
3. retrieve ID of that new record
4. continue looping over the rest of the fields
5. for every subsequent set of valid records, do an update of the previously created record and add in the new fieldset data.

Though, honestly, unless you've got some highly offbeat design need to maintain a single table with 16 sets of repeated columns, you'd be better off normalizing a bit, and maintain two seperate tables. A parent "enrollment" table, and a child "members" table. That way you can create the parent enrollment table, then just insert new children as you encounter them in the form.

update #2:

well, a simplified form of a normalized layout would be:

```
signups (id, name, etc...)
signup_members (id, signup_id, firstname, lastname)
```

and you'd pull the full signup record set with the following query:

```
SELECT signups.id, signups.name, signup_members.id, firstname, lastname
FROM signups
LEFT JOIN signup_members ON signups.id = signup_members.signup_id
ORDER BY ...
```

That would give you a series of rows, one for each 'member' signup. To build the CSV, a simple loop with some state checking to see if you've reached a new signup yet:

```
$oldid = null;
$csv = ... put column headers here if you want ...
while ($signup = $result->fetchrow()) {
    if ($signup['signups.id'] != $oldid) {
        // current signup doesn't match previous seen id, so got a new signup record
        $csv .= "\n"; // start new line in CSV
        $csv .= ... add first few columns to new csv row ...
        $oldid = $signup['signups.id']; // store new record id
    } else {
        $csv .= ... add extra member columns to current csv row ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: not sure your answer is anywhere close so perhaps it was misread or typed incorrectly. I am not taking POST variables at all in this scenario. The example shows my format for variables which is F(number variable)(field): i.e. F1FirstName. All you have done is shown me how to loop through storing the POST variables into another global which I have already done. I am trying to insert each piece of information at the end of the enrollment into a database.

Comment: thanks for the help. Honestly, the only reason we are keeping it in a single row is because the client needs to be able to pull a CSV file of DB data at various times, has no technical capability to compare 2 csv files (parent and child), and I am not sure how to compile a single csv with data from 2 or more tables

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do could be simpler, but to solve the problem, you can join the user information into one variable, separated by a char of your choice and send it to Mysql DB...

```
$user1 = $f1name . ';' . $f1address . ';' . $f1phone;
$user2 = $f2name . ';' . $f2address . ';' . $f2phone;
$user3 = $f3name . ';' . $f3address . ';' . $f3phone;

INSERT INTO table-name VALUES('$user1','$user2','$user3')
```

To extract, just "explode" the value by the ";".
If you use the same order for all users data, and if you send a verification string in case one user leaves a field blank, works just fine :)
humm... this work's just fine if the user isn't allowed to use ";" as "personal data" :)

Hope it helps U!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at "variable variables":

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Then you could conceivably loop through from 1 to 15, without having to rename your form fields.

Comment: Variable variables cannot be used with superglobals, functions or class methods.